# cannot start KVM guests with certain vcpus number

Tags: centos, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have a Supermicro server SYS-1028GR-TR, dual E5-2690 v4. It's 28 physical cores, 56 logical. I'm trying to launch 6 guests with 8 vcpus each. So far I can only start 5 guests, 6th gues is simply not starting: virsh is stuck on it's start, another virsh in different session shows the domain is *paused* state. This happens with or without setting the affinity using the `cpuset='X-Y'`directive.

This is happening under the 7.3.1611 x86_64, packages versions are as follows:

```
qemu-kvm-common-1.5.3-126.el7_3.6.x86_64
libvirt-daemon-kvm-2.0.0-10.el7_3.5.x86_64
qemu-kvm-1.5.3-126.el7_3.6.x86_64
```

Here are the diagnostics on how the OS sees the topology:

```
# virsh nodeinfo
CPU model:           x86_64
CPU(s):              56
CPU frequency:       1237 MHz
CPU socket(s):       1
Core(s) per socket:  14
Thread(s) per core:  2
NUMA cell(s):        2
Memory size:         134103980 KiB


# virsh capabilities
<capabilities>

  <host>
    <uuid>00000000-0000-0000-0000-0cc47ab4c5d0</uuid>
    <cpu>
      <arch>x86_64</arch>
      <model>Broadwell</model>
      <vendor>Intel</vendor>
      <topology sockets='1' cores='14' threads='2'/>
      <feature name='vme'/>
      <feature name='ds'/>
      <feature name='acpi'/>
      <feature name='ss'/>
      <feature name='ht'/>
      <feature name='tm'/>
      <feature name='pbe'/>
      <feature name='dtes64'/>
      <feature name='monitor'/>
      <feature name='ds_cpl'/>
      <feature name='vmx'/>
      <feature name='smx'/>
      <feature name='est'/>
      <feature name='tm2'/>
      <feature name='xtpr'/>
      <feature name='pdcm'/>
      <feature name='dca'/>
      <feature name='osxsave'/>
      <feature name='f16c'/>
      <feature name='rdrand'/>
      <feature name='arat'/>
      <feature name='tsc_adjust'/>
      <feature name='cmt'/>
      <feature name='xsaveopt'/>
      <feature name='mbm_total'/>
      <feature name='mbm_local'/>
      <feature name='pdpe1gb'/>
      <feature name='abm'/>
      <feature name='invtsc'/>
      <pages unit='KiB' size='4'/>
      <pages unit='KiB' size='2048'/>
      <pages unit='KiB' size='1048576'/>
    </cpu>
    <power_management>
      <suspend_mem/>
      <suspend_disk/>
      <suspend_hybrid/>
    </power_management>
    <migration_features>
      <live/>
      <uri_transports>
        <uri_transport>tcp</uri_transport>
        <uri_transport>rdma</uri_transport>
      </uri_transports>
    </migration_features>
    <topology>
      <cells num='2'>
        <cell id='0'>
          <memory unit='KiB'>66995116</memory>
          <pages unit='KiB' size='4'>16748779</pages>
          <pages unit='KiB' size='2048'>0</pages>
          <pages unit='KiB' size='1048576'>0</pages>
          <distances>
            <sibling id='0' value='10'/>
            <sibling id='1' value='21'/>
          </distances>
          <cpus num='28'>
            <cpu id='0' socket_id='0' core_id='0' siblings='0,28'/>
            <cpu id='1' socket_id='0' core_id='1' siblings='1,29'/>
            <cpu id='2' socket_id='0' core_id='2' siblings='2,30'/>
            <cpu id='3' socket_id='0' core_id='3' siblings='3,31'/>
            <cpu id='4' socket_id='0' core_id='4' siblings='4,32'/>
            <cpu id='5' socket_id='0' core_id='5' siblings='5,33'/>
            <cpu id='6' socket_id='0' core_id='6' siblings='6,34'/>
            <cpu id='7' socket_id='0' core_id='8' siblings='7,35'/>
            <cpu id='8' socket_id='0' core_id='9' siblings='8,36'/>
            <cpu id='9' socket_id='0' core_id='10' siblings='9,37'/>
            <cpu id='10' socket_id='0' core_id='11' siblings='10,38'/>
            <cpu id='11' socket_id='0' core_id='12' siblings='11,39'/>
            <cpu id='12' socket_id='0' core_id='13' siblings='12,40'/>
            <cpu id='13' socket_id='0' core_id='14' siblings='13,41'/>
            <cpu id='28' socket_id='0' core_id='0' siblings='0,28'/>
            <cpu id='29' socket_id='0' core_id='1' siblings='1,29'/>
            <cpu id='30' socket_id='0' core_id='2' siblings='2,30'/>
            <cpu id='31' socket_id='0' core_id='3' siblings='3,31'/>
            <cpu id='32' socket_id='0' core_id='4' siblings='4,32'/>
            <cpu id='33' socket_id='0' core_id='5' siblings='5,33'/>
            <cpu id='34' socket_id='0' core_id='6' siblings='6,34'/>
            <cpu id='35' socket_id='0' core_id='8' siblings='7,35'/>
            <cpu id='36' socket_id='0' core_id='9' siblings='8,36'/>
            <cpu id='37' socket_id='0' core_id='10' siblings='9,37'/>
            <cpu id='38' socket_id='0' core_id='11' siblings='10,38'/>
            <cpu id='39' socket_id='0' core_id='12' siblings='11,39'/>
            <cpu id='40' socket_id='0' core_id='13' siblings='12,40'/>
            <cpu id='41' socket_id='0' core_id='14' siblings='13,41'/>
          </cpus>
        </cell>
        <cell id='1'>
          <memory unit='KiB'>67108864</memory>
          <pages unit='KiB' size='4'>16777216</pages>
          <pages unit='KiB' size='2048'>0</pages>
          <pages unit='KiB' size='1048576'>0</pages>
          <distances>
            <sibling id='0' value='21'/>
            <sibling id='1' value='10'/>
          </distances>
          <cpus num='28'>
            <cpu id='14' socket_id='1' core_id='0' siblings='14,42'/>
            <cpu id='15' socket_id='1' core_id='1' siblings='15,43'/>
            <cpu id='16' socket_id='1' core_id='2' siblings='16,44'/>
            <cpu id='17' socket_id='1' core_id='3' siblings='17,45'/>
            <cpu id='18' socket_id='1' core_id='4' siblings='18,46'/>
            <cpu id='19' socket_id='1' core_id='5' siblings='19,47'/>
            <cpu id='20' socket_id='1' core_id='6' siblings='20,48'/>
            <cpu id='21' socket_id='1' core_id='8' siblings='21,49'/>
            <cpu id='22' socket_id='1' core_id='9' siblings='22,50'/>
            <cpu id='23' socket_id='1' core_id='10' siblings='23,51'/>
            <cpu id='24' socket_id='1' core_id='11' siblings='24,52'/>
            <cpu id='25' socket_id='1' core_id='12' siblings='25,53'/>
            <cpu id='26' socket_id='1' core_id='13' siblings='26,54'/>
            <cpu id='27' socket_id='1' core_id='14' siblings='27,55'/>
            <cpu id='42' socket_id='1' core_id='0' siblings='14,42'/>
            <cpu id='43' socket_id='1' core_id='1' siblings='15,43'/>
            <cpu id='44' socket_id='1' core_id='2' siblings='16,44'/>
            <cpu id='45' socket_id='1' core_id='3' siblings='17,45'/>
            <cpu id='46' socket_id='1' core_id='4' siblings='18,46'/>
            <cpu id='47' socket_id='1' core_id='5' siblings='19,47'/>
            <cpu id='48' socket_id='1' core_id='6' siblings='20,48'/>
            <cpu id='49' socket_id='1' core_id='8' siblings='21,49'/>
            <cpu id='50' socket_id='1' core_id='9' siblings='22,50'/>
            <cpu id='51' socket_id='1' core_id='10' siblings='23,51'/>
            <cpu id='52' socket_id='1' core_id='11' siblings='24,52'/>
            <cpu id='53' socket_id='1' core_id='12' siblings='25,53'/>
            <cpu id='54' socket_id='1' core_id='13' siblings='26,54'/>
            <cpu id='55' socket_id='1' core_id='14' siblings='27,55'/>
          </cpus>
        </cell>
      </cells>
    </topology>
    <secmodel>
      <model>selinux</model>
      <doi>0</doi>
      <baselabel type='kvm'>system_u:system_r:svirt_t:s0</baselabel>
      <baselabel type='qemu'>system_u:system_r:svirt_tcg_t:s0</baselabel>
    </secmodel>
    <secmodel>
      <model>dac</model>
      <doi>0</doi>
      <baselabel type='kvm'>+107:+107</baselabel>
      <baselabel type='qemu'>+107:+107</baselabel>
    </secmodel>
  </host>

  <guest>
    <os_type>hvm</os_type>
    <arch name='i686'>
      <wordsize>32</wordsize>
      <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
      <machine maxCpus='240'>pc-i440fx-rhel7.0.0</machine>
      <machine canonical='pc-i440fx-rhel7.0.0' maxCpus='240'>pc</machine>
      <machine maxCpus='240'>rhel6.0.0</machine>
      <machine maxCpus='240'>rhel6.1.0</machine>
      <machine maxCpus='240'>rhel6.2.0</machine>
      <machine maxCpus='240'>rhel6.3.0</machine>
      <machine maxCpus='240'>rhel6.4.0</machine>
      <machine maxCpus='240'>rhel6.5.0</machine>
      <machine maxCpus='240'>rhel6.6.0</machine>
      <domain type='qemu'/>
      <domain type='kvm'>
        <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
      </domain>
    </arch>
    <features>
      <cpuselection/>
      <deviceboot/>
      <disksnapshot default='off' toggle='no'/>
      <acpi default='on' toggle='yes'/>
      <apic default='on' toggle='no'/>
      <pae/>
      <nonpae/>
    </features>
  </guest>

  <guest>
    <os_type>hvm</os_type>
    <arch name='x86_64'>
      <wordsize>64</wordsize>
      <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
      <machine maxCpus='240'>pc-i440fx-rhel7.0.0</machine>
      <machine canonical='pc-i440fx-rhel7.0.0' maxCpus='240'>pc</machine>
      <machine maxCpus='240'>rhel6.0.0</machine>
      <machine maxCpus='240'>rhel6.1.0</machine>
      <machine maxCpus='240'>rhel6.2.0</machine>
      <machine maxCpus='240'>rhel6.3.0</machine>
      <machine maxCpus='240'>rhel6.4.0</machine>
      <machine maxCpus='240'>rhel6.5.0</machine>
      <machine maxCpus='240'>rhel6.6.0</machine>
      <domain type='qemu'/>
      <domain type='kvm'>
        <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
      </domain>
    </arch>
    <features>
      <cpuselection/>
      <deviceboot/>
      <disksnapshot default='off' toggle='no'/>
      <acpi default='on' toggle='yes'/>
      <apic default='on' toggle='no'/>
    </features>
  </guest>

</capabilities>
```

Comment: Seems like when adding more vcpus, KVM starts to eat more memory for each host. Dj last one just doesn't get enough memory.

Comment: Paused might mean you're hitting a disk io bottleneck. Or running out of disk space. Are you using sparse disks?

Comment: Consider posting to [**Virtualization & Emulation**](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/100140/virtualization-emulation) for a more specific site.